# Having problem setting 'charset=utf8' with peewee and pymysql

Tags: mysql, database, utf-8, pymysql, peewee

I got some problem setting utf8 on my database table.

I followed these documents but not working

docs for pymsql:
https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/connections.html

docs for peewee:
http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#using-mysql

here is my code

```
import datetime

from peewee import *
import pymysql
from getDataFromExcel import *

mysql_db = MySQLDatabase(
    databasename,
    user='username',
    password='password',
    host='host',
    charset='utf8', # <-- what I followed from docs

    )

class BaseModel(Model):
    """A base model that will use our MySQL database """
    class Meta:
        database = mysql_db


class Food(BaseModel):
    name = CharField()
    allergy = CharField()
    special = CharField()
    createdAt = DateTimeField(default = datetime.datetime.now)
    updatedAt =DateTimeField(default = datetime.datetime.now)
    class Meta:
        table_name='Food'


def initialize():
    """Create the database and the table if they don't exist."""

    mysql_db.connect()
    print('Initialized')


def insert_food_data(food_rows):
    with mysql_db.atomic():
        Food.insert_many(food_rows,fields=[
            Food.name,
            Food.allergy,
            Food.special
        ]).execute()


if __name__ =='__main__':
    initialize()
```

I run this using 
`python3 -i filename.py`

after that, I put some more code interactively(drop existing table and create new table to check utf8 setting is done)

```
mysql_db.execute_sql("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0")
mysql_db.drop_tables([Food])
mysql_db.create_tables([Food])
```

but when I check my data base with MySQLWorkbench.
the DDL tap of my table says

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `allergy` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `special` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

that means charset has set with 'latin1' 
and I can know that by inserting some data in it.

why is that?

did I something wrong setting charset ase uf8 ?

It would be really appreciated if somebody can help me.

Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 1):

That sets the charset of the connection. To change your default charset on the table, you can modify `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server  = utf8
collation-server      = utf8_general_ci
character_set_server   = utf8
collation_server       = utf8_general_ci
```

You can also specify `Model.meta.table_settings` to specify the charset for a given table explicitly.

```
class MyModel(Model):
    # ... fields, etc ...
    class Meta:
        database = my_db
        table_settings = ['ENGINE=InnoDB', 'DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8']
```

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#model-options-and-table-metadata

Comment: None of these suggestions change settings for _existing_ tables or columns.

Comment: OP is dropping and recreating the table. The suggestions will resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

- A table and its columns have a specified encoding for characters.  (latin1, in your case)
- The *client* has an encoding.  This indicates the way accented letters, etc, are encoded in 1 byte (for latin1) or 2 bytes (for utf8), etc.
- You tell MySQL what the *client* encoding is through 3 settings --

  ```
  character_set_client
  character_set_connection
  character_set_results
  ```

Those are probably set indirectly from one of things you told peewee or pymysql.
* When an `INSERT` or `SELECT` occurs, the *client* encoding is turned into the column's encoding on the fly.

`latin1` is fine for Western European languages, but is inadequate for the rest of the world.